# Error in tapply(auto_data$average.mpg, auto_data$company, mean) : arguments must have same length

Tags: r

## Read in the auto.csv file

```
auto_data <- read.csv("auto1.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

## Total number of cars for each company

```
car_counts=cat("Total cars of all companies: ", nrow(auto_data), "\n")
```

## Average mileage of all companies

```
avg_mileage <- tapply(auto_data$average.mpg, auto_data$company, mean)
print(avg_mileage)
```

> Error in tapply(auto_data$average.mpg, auto_data$company, mean) :
> arguments must have same length

Comment: Could you provide us with an example of what your data looks like, and what is your desired output is? Try pasting the output of `head(dput(auto_data))` add a start. It should begin with `structure(…`.